# Kotlin Upload Image to Firebase Animation or setContentLayout to another activity while uploading

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I want to show an animation (like loading bar) while the photo is being uploaded to the firebase or set the content layout to the user's profile and show an animation there while the photo is being uploaded.

Right now, when I click "Share" button it just acts like the "Share" isn't clicked so user's click it multiple times without knowing that there will be as many photos as many times they clicked "Share"

here is my share function:

```
fun share(user: User, imageUri: Uri?, caption: String) {

    if (imageUri != null) {
        usersRepo.uploadUserImage(user.uid, imageUri).onSuccessTask { downloadUrl ->
            Tasks.whenAll(
                    feedPostsRepo.createFeedPost(user.uid, mkFeedPost(user, caption,
                            downloadUrl.toString()))
            )
        }.addOnCompleteListener{
            _shareCompletedEvent.call()
        }.addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `ProgressBar` to your `activity`/`fragment` content `xml`

```
     <!-- Set colors etc as per your choice -->
     <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar_myActivity"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:foregroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

And when share `button` is `clicked` you show the `ProgressBar` and disable the screen interaction using

```
progressBar_myActivity.visibility = View.VISIBLE  //show progress bar
window.setFlags(                                  //disable view for user interaction
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
)
```

And once you get the `api` `response` you can show the appropriate message and hide the `ProgressBar` and enable user interaction using

```
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
progressBar_myActivity.visibility = View.GONE
// show appropriate message
```

***Please note that if your api response takes considerable amount of time, then try to move them to some other UI element as halting interaction for long times is not very good UI/UX feature***.